# Make global method accessible in classes

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Consider the following `sinatra` application:

```
require 'sinatra'

def f
    settings.development? ? 'development' : 'whatever'
end

class C
    def self.f
        settings.development? ? 'development' : 'whatever'
    end
end

get '/' do
    # f   # works
    C.f   # doesn't work, gives "NameError - undefined local variable or method `settings' for C:Class"
end
```

What's happening here and how do I make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
class C
  def self.f
    Sinatra::Application.settings.development? ? 'development' : 'whatever'
  end
end
```

What happens is that when you `require 'sinatra'` the [following](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/main.rb#L30) happens:

> ```
> # include would include the module in Object
> # extend only extends the `main` object
> extend Sinatra::Delegator
> ```

The `Sinatra::Delegator` class is the one responsible for having [`settings`](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1991) available in the `main` object, as well as the `get` DSL and all the goodies you need to create a [classic](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Modular%20vs.%20Classic%20Style) Sinatra application.

Comment: Alternatively `class C < Sinatra::Application`, then omit `Sinatra::Application` inside `self.f` would also work, I think.

Comment: But could you explain what's happening here? `settings` is a method of `Sinatra::Application`, right? How come it's accessible from top-level methods?

Answer (score 1):

What happens is, you lose access to the outer scope when defining new class, since it gives you its own scope.

As [Uri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1120015/uri-agassi) mentioned above, requiring Sinatra runs  `extend Sinatra::Delegator` which adds all the well-known methods.

Consider this over-simplification:

```
module A
  def ping
    "pong"
  end
end

ping # => throws NoMethodError
extend A
ping # => "pong"

class B
  def my_ping
    ping
  end
end

B.new.my_ping # => throws NoMethodError
```

Why? Because of the Ruby's scoping rules.

You can work around this by passing a reference to the outer scope.

```
module A
  def ping
    "pong"
  end
end

extend A
ping # => "pong"

class B
  class << self
    attr_accessor :app

    def my_ping
      app.ping
    end
  end
end

B.app = self
B.my_ping # => "pong"
```